# "Минифутбол"

Tags: орфография

Набрала в Яндексе "минифутбол".
Открылись три разных написания: *мини-футбол, минифутбол, мини футбол*.
Как правильно?
А "мини-юбка"? Или "миниюбка"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мини-футбол, мини-юбка (Полный орфографический словарь под ред. Лопатина)